# Возврат из функции массива

Tags: php

Пытаюсь вернуть массив из функции, но он не передаётся. Что я делаю не так?

```
function myfun($var){
    if (условие1){
    $arr = array (Первый набор значений);
    }
    if (условие2) {
    $arr = array (Второй набор значений);
    }
    else {
    $arr = array (Третий набор значений);
    }

    return $arr;
 }
```

**Добавлено:**
Данная функция вызывается из другого файла и там же проверяется возврат значения

```
global $arr; //вначале файла
...
myfun('myavar');
echo "arr= ".$arr;
```

Вывод пустой.

Сама функция работает, принимает передаваемый `myavar` и печатает массив. Но не возвращает в первоначальный файл.

Comment: и как вы функцию вызываете, и проверяете возвращаемое значение?

Comment: @teran Вызывается из другого файла ( работает, проверено. global обявлено) и там же проверяется через `echo`. Тут получается пусто.

Comment: наоборот все у вас. в начале файла вы (должны) объявляете просто переменную `$arr`, а вот уже во функции вы пишите, что она глобальная-внешняя `global $arr`, из глобальной области видимости.

Comment: @Ипатьев Тамошние ответа не решают или как минимум не помогли решению моей проблемы!!! Отрройте пож вопрос.

Comment: Делай как там написано и все получится.

Comment: @Ипатьев как, "как там"? Открой вопрос - может кто понятный ответ даст

Comment: @sto фактически решит, если вы напишите `$arr = myfun(..);`. либо помееяйте местами объявления global, но тогда и возвращать ничего не надо.

Comment: @teran я не понял.. где надо где не надо объявлять глобальную?

Comment: чтобы это работало в функции  надо написать `global $arr`.

Comment: @sto ваш вопрос закрыт дублем, в котором указано именно то, как вы решили.

Comment: @teran вот зачем ты ребенка плохому учишь?

Comment: @Ипатьев чему именно? я ему пояснил, в чем ошибка в его реализации через глобал. В данном контексте это важно, поскольку ошибка и непонимание есть. После того, как это непонимание будет устранено, уже можно обсудить само по себе использование глобальных переменных и возвратов массивов.

Comment: `return $arr;`. Расскажи мне ещё что тут реализация с глобал